# Append value to an XML SELECT result

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am trying to fetch an XML from a table and append an XML element to it. I don't want to physically update the XML in DB. Only the SELECT result has to be modified.

Suppose we have an XML field with this blob,

```
<Test>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Name>test123</Name>
</Test>
```

and we want to append a Type element to this

```
<Test>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Name>test123</Name>
   <Type>Employee</Type>
</Test>
```

how would we achieve this using postgres XML functions? The postgres documentation for XML functions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-xml.html) does not seem to have an add_child method. In fact, postgres has offered very few methods for XML, unlike Strings. I did not find any method to modify an XML data using SQL queries without having to fetch them from DB, modify them in the application and update the table with the modified entry. Although my use-case does not require me to modify the data in DB, I would like to make use of any such function along with a SELECT query to achieve my use-case. Is there a way I can achieve this with a single query?

Comment: Yes it can be done, however as you noticed there isn't a great way to do it. So it depends on how complex your data is. If you need it to be able to handle xml without knowing anything about it in advance, you'll probably want to create a function that takes it apart and can put it back together without losing any data (e.g. attributes). If you know it's always in some format it may be quicker to do some string manipulation to insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the nicest way, but it will do what you want:

```
SELECT 
    '<Test>' ||
    xmlconcat(
        xmlagg(parts),
        xmlelement(name "Type", null, 'Employee')
    ) ||
    '</Test>'
FROM
    unnest(
        xpath('/Test/*', '<Test><ID>1</ID><Name>test123</Name></Test>')
    ) AS parts;
```

First, it takes all children of `Test` element with `xpath()` function. Then those parts are aggregated and concatenated with new `Type` element. At the end the root element `Test` is added again.

Comment: Well, this would work. I require this to be a part of a larger query, which already reads the xml blob. I will send the xml data to the XPath query to achieve the same. It is quite surprising to know there isn't a straightforward append_child kind of method. Thanks for your input.